# bcrypt.compare() always returns false when verifying passwords

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, bcrypt, sequelize.js

I followed [this tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) from scotch.io on how to build user authentication using node.js (great tutorial by the way). However, when `verifyPassword(password)` is called to check user password, the value is always returned as false for some reason.

I'm using brcypt.js and sequelize.js for my express project.

#### custom methods for model User:

```
classMethods : {

     setPassword : function(password) {

          return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);

    }

},
instanceMethods: {

     verifyPassword: function(password) {
           return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, result) {

            if (err) throw err;
            return result;

          });
    }

}
```

#### this is how i create a new user:

```
User.find({where: {email : email}})
    .complete(function(err, user) {

  // if there are any errors, return the error
  if (err){
      return done(err);
  }

  // check to see if theres already a user with that email
  if (user) {
     return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
  } else {


            User
              .create({
                email: email,
                password: User.setPassword(password)

              })
              .complete(function(err, newUser) {
                if (err) 
                    throw err;
                return done(null, newUser)
        })


         }

});
```

#### verifying password:

```
User.find({where: { email :  email }})
        .complete(function(err, user) {

        if (err)
            return done(err);

        if (!user){

            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 
        }
        // if the user is found but the password is wrong

        if (!user.verifyPassword(password)){

            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
        }
        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, user);
    });
```

I know its better to use async mode in bcrypt but it always gives me "password undefined" when I try something like this:

```
setPassword : function(password) {
    return bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            if (err) return err;
        return bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) return err;
                return hash;
        });
    });
 }
```

what should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bcrypt.compare appears to be asynchronous, you should extend your compare function to take a callback.

You could do the same for setPassword but you'll have to do your create inside the callback. You're using it in a synchronous matter right now so it will have to be a synchronous function.

You could do something like:

```
classMethods : {
  setPassword : function(password, callback) {       
    // Pseudo, i don't actually know the bcrypt api
    return bcrypt.hash(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), callback);
  }
},
instanceMethods: {
  verifyPassword: function(password, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, callback);
  }
}
```

And then rewrite your interfacing code to something like:

```
Uset.setPassword(password, function (err, password) {
  if (err) return done(err);
  User.create({
    email: email,
    password: password
  }).done(done);
});

user.verifyPassword(password, function (err, result) {
  if (err || result) return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
  return done(null, user);
});
```

Encrypting passwords on create is where hooks come in handy, instead of handling the encrypting yourself you could use a beforeCreate hook to encrypt the password before it gets saved.

```
User.beforeCreate(function (model, done) {
  bcrypt.hash(model.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), function (err, password) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    model.password = password;
    done();
  });
});

User.create({
  email: email,
  password: password // Unencrypted
});
```

The before create will then make sure the value is encrypted before it is inserted to the database.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. i made changes according to your answer. but user can always login no matter if the password is correct or not. also, the result is always returned as false

Comment: i didnt get how to use beforeCreate method. should i also declare it as a classMethod in the model and call it when i want to create a user? thanks

Comment: Hi, i solved the problem. turns out it was my setter method. i set it like: this.setDataValue('password', newPassword.toString().toLowercase) and so the hash are all converted to lowercase. thanks for your help!

Comment: No you declare the hook on the model, like i provided in the example.
Glad you solved your issue.

Comment: omg! i was having the same problem. Thanks for mentioning the lowercase setter.