# User authentication with password created by Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, bcrypt

I am trying to authenticate user from server, using password created in Meteor by accounts-password and stored in DB. However passwords never match. What I am doing wrong?

```
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var raw_pass = 'my_pass';
    var pass = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(raw_pass).digest('hex');              
    var encryptedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
    bcrypt.compare(doc.services.password.bcrypt, encryptedPassword, function(err, result) {
                if(result) {
                   console.log('OK');
                }
                else {
                   console.log(403);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments for bcrypt.compare are 'plain string' and 'encrypted string'. So the right solution is:

```
var raw_pass = 'my_pass';
var pass-256 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(raw_pass).digest('hex');              
bcrypt.compare(meteor.password, pass-256, function(err, result) {
            if(result) {
               console.log('OK');
            }
            else {
               console.log(403);
            }
        });
```

Comment: it doesn't work this way. meteor use bcrypt and salt (10 by default) to generate the password after the plaintext pwd being sha256 encrypted
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js

Answer (score 2):

The right way to check a plain password against a meteor generated one is by using sha256 and bcrypt as follows

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
var sha256 = require('sha256')
const samePassword = bcrypt.compareSync(
                        sha256(plainTextPassword),
                        user.services.password.bcrypt
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help us if you print out the output of `bcrypt.compare`.
It might be returning 0, which would mean success, but in your if statement, 0 would be interpreted as false.

Comment: The result is always 'false' (boolean) regardless correct/incorrect password.

Comment: What is doc.services.password.bcrypt? Shouldn't it be `pass`?

Comment: Sorry for a confusion. It is password in DB stored by Meteor in services/password/bcrypt.

Comment: There are a few other questions on this site about `bcrypt.compare`. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092581/bcrypt-compare-always-returns-false-when-verifying-passwords) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Account password doesn't use crypto for the password.
It's only use bcrypt and salt to generate the encrypted password.

You can check compare password [here](https://github.com/meteor/accounts/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L61)

Comment: I don't think it is true.                                                                               // Use bcrypt to hash the password for storage in the database.
// `password` can be a string (in which case it will be run through
// SHA256 before bcrypt) or an object with properties `digest` and
// `algorithm` (in which case we bcrypt `password.digest`).
//

Comment: Yes You care right.https://github.com/meteor/accounts/blob/77b6084c0bd24129c1e7a6d703d9effddaceadcb/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L65

Comment: Yes. it's use rsa 256 and digest.